# Using the word "Shy" to mean "Attempt"?

Tags: word-usage, nouns, synonyms

Is anyone familiar with the informal usage of the word 'shy' with the same meaning as 'attempt'? I've seen people use phrases like, '1st shy, 2nd shy' etc.

If such usage is correct, I would like to know its origins.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? Can you give an example of this use in context?

Comment: I suspect this is using the "to throw (an object) with a jerk" definition in some specialize context where it would be common jargon. It is certainly not a typical meaning of "shy".

Comment: I've found an example of this use in a facebook page for "2011 A/L 1st shy students' union", and https://medium.com/@rajafaslur/happened-to-do-a-l-2nd-shy-no-worries-its-for-the-best-7ac19ff403b3 from the University of Jaffna.  I think this is a Sri Lankan English dialect use, probably related to the sense of "Throw" as in the game of shying at coconuts.  Each "shy" is an attempt to hit a coconut.

Comment: I'm sure I've heard baseball announcers use "shy" to mean throw, especially if it's not in the strike zone, but can't find any references. It would be something like, "*He shies one high and away*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage seems to be Sri Lankan dialect. It is used particularly in reference to attempts at examinations (and more specifically A-level examinations):

> I have a experience of second shy.
> (Although I entered medicine with my first shy results due to results problems in 2011.)
>
> 1st shy ABB Physics — A , Z-Score 2.11
> 2nd shy, 3A — Z-Score 2.1455 — Island rank — 237

This use isn't common in the UK.  It seems to be related to the meaning of "shy: throw with a jerk".  There are games in which one throws (or shies) balls at coconuts.  Each throw is an attempt to hit a coconut.  The dialect use seems to be related to this sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Chambers Dictionary](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=shy&title=21st) has

> **shy²** *noun*
>
> **1** a fling or throw.
> . . .
> **3** *colloq* an attempt or shot.
> . . .

Chambers gives the etymology for the 'timid' meaning, but not for this.

---

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?page=1&q=shy&type=) says about the verb form

> **shy** (v.1)
> "to throw (a missile) with a jerk or toss"
> 1787, colloquial, of unknown origin and uncertain connection to **shy** (adj.)